# Session attribute returns null in Jsp

Tags: jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am working on JSP and getting null value in session, here is my code

```
LoginServlet.java
        String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
        String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
        if(userId.equals("test") && password.equals("test"))
        {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", userId); //session is set
            try 
            {
                response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and in `LoginSuccess.jsp` I am retriving it like

```
Logged in user  = <% session.getAttribute("user");%>
```

but it returns null, not getting the reason why?

Comment: Maybe, check your jsp file if it contains <% session.invalidate()%> .

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to create a instance of session in JSP.
JSP is providing you inbuilt objects of all :- session , out, request , response..etc

```
String user=(String)session.getAttribute("user");
```

It will give you user value,
and also make sure that when you are setting user value in session `session.setAttribute("user", userId); //session is set` it is not null.
just sysout that value.

Comment: `session.setAttribute("user", userId);` userId is not null and I am using session from jsp only.

Comment: can you try to retrieve that value in same java file, and it is getting or not..?

Comment: and for null pointer exception you can try this.
String folglobal=request.getParameter("FolderValue")!=null?request.getParameter("FolderValue").toString():"";

Comment: there might be problem of casting.
try put some static string then. print it on jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong; but, in your LoginSuccess.jsp file, try changing the request.getParamater("UserId"); to "userId" with a lower-case u. In your servlet, you defined it with a lower-case. Make sure the names match

Comment: and what about `session.getAttribute("user");`?

Comment: I have removed taking it from request. I only want it from session.

Answer (score 0):

String user = <% (String)session.getAttribute("user");%>